# Drop down menu filter for SELECT COUNT results php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, filter

I have a script which retrieves all rows of data within a sales list (npc_sales_list) but what I am trying to do is set up a drop down menu which filters the results oand I don't know where to start as I haven't done any php in while.

The main filters I am trying to do are to see the previous month's sales only (npc_entry_date) and the sales type (npc_usertype). If someone could point me in the right direction or show me some resource links that would be great.

Im not fussed whether the filter is automatic or if you need to hit a submit button. Any suggestions welcome...

```
        <?php 
        require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');
        $page_title = 'Page title';
        include ('./includes/header.html');

        if (!isset($_SESSION['admin_sp_id'])) {
           $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
            . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
           if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
                $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); 
           }
           $url .= '/login.php'; 

        ob_end_clean(); 
        header("Location: $url"); 
        exit(); 
        }

        require_once ('database.php');
        $display = 500;

        if (isset($_GET['np'])) { 
            $num_pages = $_GET['np'];
        } else { 

            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM npc_sales_list ORDER BY npc_entry_date DESC";   
            $result = @mysql_query ($query);
            $row = mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_NUM);
            $num_records = $row[0];

            if ($num_records > $display) { 
               $num_pages = ceil ($num_records/$display);
            } else {
               $num_pages = 1;
            }

        } 
        if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
            $start = $_GET['s'];
        } else {
            $start = 0;
        }
        $link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fna";
        $link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lna";

        if (isset($_GET['sort'])) {

            switch ($_GET['sort']) {
               case 'fna':
                  $order_by = 'sp_firstname ASC';
                  $link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fnd";
                  break;
               case 'fnd':
                  $order_by = 'sp_firstname DESC';
                  $link1 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=fna";
                  break;
               case 'lna':
                  $order_by = 'sp_surname ASC';
                  $link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lnd";
                  break;
               case 'lnd':
                  $order_by = 'sp_surname DESC';
                  $link2 = "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sort=lna";
                  break;
               default:
                  $order_by = 'npc_entry_date DESC';
                  break;
            }

            // $sort will be appended to the pagination links.
            $sort = $_GET['sort'];

        } else { // Use the default sorting order.
            $order_by = 'npc_entry_date DESC';
            $sort = 'drd';
        }

        $query = "SELECT us.sp_firstname , us.sp_surname , us.sp_amb_club_no , us.sp_position_title , us.sp_dealer_name , 
            us.sp_dealer_code , us.sp_region , us.sp_department, sp_business_phone, us.sp_mobile_phone , us.sp_dealer_category, us.sp_email, 
            sa.npc_item_id , sa.npc_part_no, sa.npc_quantity, sa.npc_customer_name, sa.npc_registration_no , sa.npc_suo_no , sa.npc_amb_club_no , sa.npc_repair_order , sa.npc_invoice_no , 
            sa.npc_entry_userdate, sa.npc_image_upload, sa.npc_usertype, sa.npc_points, sa.npc_bonus_points, sa.npc_active, sa.npc_entry_date, 
            DATE_FORMAT(sa.npc_entry_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS dr , sa.sp_user_id 
            FROM sp_user AS us, npc_sales_list AS sa 
            WHERE us.sp_user_id = sa.sp_user_id
            ORDER BY
            $order_by LIMIT $start, $display";

        $result = @mysql_query ($query); 

        // <a href="' . $link4 . '"></a>
        // Table header.
        echo '<table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" style="font-size:10px;">
            <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>Invoice No.</b></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="' . $link1 . '"><b>Member ID</b></a></td>
            <td align="center"><a href="' . $link2 . '"><b>Surname</b></a></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Part #</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Sale Type</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Qty</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Invoice Date</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Customer Rego</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Submission Date</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Status</b></td>
            </tr>';

        // Fetch and print all the records. echo '<td align="left"><strong>' . $row['sp_invoice_no'] . '</strong></td> ';
        $bg = '#ffffff'; // Set the background color.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $bg = ($bg=='#eaeced' ? '#ffffff' : '#eaeced');    
            echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';
            echo '<td align="center"><strong><a href="audit_invoice.php?id=' . $row['npc_item_id'] . '">Details</a></strong></td>  ';
            echo '<td align="center"><strong>' . $row['sp_amb_club_no'] . '</strong></td> ';
            echo '<td align="center"><strong>' . $row['sp_surname'] . '</strong></td> ';
            echo  '<td align="center"> <strong>' . $row['npc_part_no'] . '<strong></td>';
            echo  '<td align="center"> ' . $row['npc_usertype'] . ' </td>';
            echo  '<td align="center"> ' . $row['npc_quantity'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td align="center"> ' . $row['npc_entry_userdate'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td align="center"> ' . $row['npc_registration_no'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td align="center"> ' . $row['dr'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td align="center" style="color:#5a8e22; font-weight:bold;"> ' . $row['npc_active'] . ' </td>';
            echo  '</tr>
            ';
            }

        echo '</table>';

        mysql_free_result ($result);
        mysql_close();  

        if ($num_pages > 1) {

            echo '<br /><p>';
            $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

            if ($current_page != 1) {
               echo '<a href="view-all-sales.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&np=' .
                 $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">Previous</a> ';   
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
               if ($i != $current_page) {
                  echo '<a href="view-all-sales.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . 
                    '&np=' . $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">' . $i . '</a> ';   
               } else {
                  echo $i . ' ';
               }
            }
            if ($current_page != $num_pages) {
               echo '<a href="view-all-sales.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&np=' . 
                 $num_pages . '&sort=' . $sort .'">Next</a> ';   
            }
            echo '</p>';
        } 
        include ('./includes/footer_admin_user.html'); 
        ?>
```

Comment: you can build your filter in a similar fashion you have your sorts

Comment: How would I do it though?

Comment: You setup a form on top of the report, and set your fields, and then submit to the php for processing, before your query use test conditions to build the part of the `WHERE` clause